# CSS Reverse Animation on mouseleave

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a two-step CSS animation that I want to run forward once when "activated", and then run backward when "deactivated". I know it's possible to achieve by defining separate forward and backward animations, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh5g/12/), but I was wondering if this was achievable with a single animation and the `animation-direction: reverse` property.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? If so what you're looking for is

```
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

If you need to attach it to a click you can add script to it in order to `toggleClass` with `onClick`

```css
#test{
    position:absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #A8A8A8;
    border-bottom: 0px solid black;
    
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#test:hover{
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    background: aqua;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 0; 
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    transition: border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease;
    transition: all 3s ease;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
}

div:hover {
    background: red;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
    transition: border-radius 1.5s ease-in;
  
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease;
    transition: all 3s ease;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```